# Cassandra trigger explanation

Tags: cassandra, triggers

I could not find any proper documentation on Cassandra triggers. Can anyone please explain how they actually work, I mean right from the client making a write request to when the trigger is fired by the coordinator node? 
If some documentation is present then a link to that would also work.

Answer (score 1):

Whenever the client makes a write query request to the Cassandra cluster, it goes to a coordinator node which first runs the trigger, and then the query is executed in batch logged form.

References:

1. https://www.datastax.com/blog/2013/08/whats-new-cassandra-20-prototype-triggers-support
2. https://docs.datastax.com/en/dse/6.0/cql/cql/cql_using/useBatch.html